# How do I specify non greedy mode in this python regular expression situation?

Tags: python, regex, greedy

This is the string:

```
a.sticker{-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased}.noUi-value{width:40px}.noUi-value-sub{color:#ccc;font-size:10px} asdasd }
```

And I want to match only

```
.noUi-value-sub{color:#ccc;font-size:10px}
```

and I tried the following python regular expression:

```
\..*?{.+?font-size.*?}
```

You can fiddle with it in this [debug environment:](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5C..*%3F%7B.%2B%3Ffont-size.*%3F%7D&test_string=a.sticker%7B-webkit-font-smoothing%3Aantialiased%7D.noUi-value%7Bwidth%3A40px%7D.noUi-value-sub%7Bcolor%3A%23ccc%3Bfont-size%3A10px%7D%20asdasd%20%7D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

The third '?' in the above expression does the expected thing and makes the search the smallest possible. But the first two '?' don't seem to work, and seem to go for the largest possible match. What am I missing?

thanks much for taking a look.

Comment: if you only want to match that why do you need regex? why not use `find`?

Comment: I am looking for that pattern which has '{', '}', '.' and 'font-size' all in the right places as in the above pattern. Not the exact string. Hence the hunt for the elusive regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the first `.` to `[^{]` and the second to `[^}]` and it worked

```
\.[^{]*?{[^}]+?font-size.*?}
```

[Test here](https://pythex.org/?regex=%5C..*%3F%7B.%2B%3Ffont-size.*%3F%7D&test_string=a.sticker%7B-webkit-font-smoothing%3Aantialiased%7D.noUi-value%7Bwidth%3A40px%7D.noUi-value-sub%7Bcolor%3A%23ccc%3Bfont-size%3A10px%7D%20asdasd%20%7D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Comment: this indeed works! thank you. I am wondering why mine didn't and yours does. Will dig into it, if you have time an explanation would be much appreciated.

Comment: I am tentatively accepting this, although I am still mystified as to why this works.